# Bootstrap Icon inside input and button on left

Tags: css, button, input, icons, font-awesome

Currently, I have this (icon inside input, on left side):
[image]

Ideally, I would like to achieve this:
[image]

I have tried using input-group-addon for icon on left, but the shadow on focus does not look right when I remove the right border of input-group-addon and left border of input. Perhaps there's a way to add glow to input-group-addon to unify it all?

Core html and css:

```
<div id="search">
  <i id="search-icon" class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." id="search-input" />
</div>

#search { position: relative; }
#search-input { padding-left: 30px; }
#search-icon { position: absolute; padding: 10px 10px; }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8s5jm75u/

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: U want to add the blue border in both search icon and button
Or you want to remove it from input
Can you please clarify what you want?

Comment: Ideally, I want to keep the core html and css and just add button to right of input. If the only way to achieve that is by using input-group with input-group-addon and input-group-btn, then I would like the blue glow around the icon and input on focus to make it look like one.

Answer (score 0):

to make the button glow with the input you can use this css

```
.form-control:focus + .input-group-btn button{
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
```

You can keep you icon inside the input like the first one

You can also add css if you would like to remove the right border/shadow of the input box.

If you can specify exactly what you need i can help you out

**Edit:**
Or you can use the refresh icon of Font awesome the same way you used the search icon to insert it in

Comment: The refresh Icon has to be inside a button. I can put icons on both sides inside the input, but I want icon inside the input on the left side, and button outside, but on the the same line on the right side of input

Comment: I want the icon side to glow, not the button side.I tried replacing '.input-group-btn button' with '.input-group-addon' but didn't work.

Comment: You want the refresh icon inside the button to glow?